# get href of button and img

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jsp

i am no little knowledge about js and html,i have a html like:

```
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
  <title>aa</title>
 </head>

 <body><input name="button" type="button" value="hello"    onclick="window.location.href('http://hao.360.cn/')" />
<input name="button" type="submit" value="helio" onclick="window.open('http://hao.360.cn/')"/>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<a href="fg726p.exe"><img src="a2.jpg" width="156" height="152" border="0" longdesc="eclipse.exe.lnk" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to using js to get respectively the string http://hao.360.cn/ of the two buttons and  also  get the string fg726p.exe and eclipse.exe.lnk of img?

i want to using the js to get the values for android java methods. i  want to get help.

edit: through some people think it is so basic,butfor me i  know clue to search it 
can you give me some advice and link

edit2:  i adjust :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
<title>aa</title>
<script language="javascript"> 
 function get(){ 
  var xx=document.getElementById("bbs") 
 alert("："+xx.title); 
 } 
 function getElementName(){ 
var ele = document.getElementById("link1"); 
alert("：" + ele.href); 
} 
</script>
```

```
<body><input name="button" id="bbs"   title="http://homepage.yesky.com/59/2673059.apk" type="button" value="hello" onclick="get()" />
 <input name="button2" type="submit" value="helio" onclick="getElementName()"/>
 <body bgcolor="#000000">
 <a href="http://homepage.yesky.com/59/2673059.apk"  id="link1"  name="a2">   <img src="a2.jpg" width="156" height="152" border="0"  onclick="getElementName()" /></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

i have solved my problem,but i donot know why somepeople post Negative Scores give me for no little js knowledge.may be you know more,think this easy. i only want to
 get  the sting to use,i think if you know more you only answer document.getElementById("link1").href also can help me not give me all the html document. i want to string to use for my android app, i think i donot because the small problem to study the all html. the project not give you more time

edit3:
       var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

```
   var el =x.item(0);
   alert(el.getAttribute("value"));
   alert(el.getAttribute("onclick"));

   el =x.item(1);
   alert(el.getAttribute("value"));
   alert(el.getAttribute("onclick"));


    x=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   el =x.item(0);
   alert(el.getAttribute("href"));

    x=el.getElementsByTagName("img");
   el =x.item(0);
   alert(el.getAttribute("longdesc"));​
```

thank you @jmoreno for this answer for my frist question very good.i put answer here so that prevent the link of he give is broken .

Comment: hi pengwang, I have setup a demo for you how to select the properties of html-elements in Javascript here : http://jsfiddle.net/59DnP/

Comment: To get this worked, you need to add the jQuery library `<script src="jQuery.min.1.7.0.js" language="javascript"/>` and put the code in between `<script>...</script>` tags

Comment: thank you,this only a small html,i not need add the jqlib,but also thank you very much. i also accept it.thank you  again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are generating that HTML, be aware it has a couple of problems with it.  1) JavaScript and DOM manipulation work best when specific tags have id's, 2) the body tag is present twice.

But within the limits of what you have posted, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_planb/BqGs5/1/).

The heart of it being the `...getAttribute("onclick")` where given a element in the DOM, you get the required attribute (onclick, href, longdesc).

I leave it to you to parse out the sub string you want.

Answer (score 1):

You code seems to be a little messed up.

1. You are using `body` 2 times. Setting the bgcolor as you do is really old fashioned, when you want to set the background color inline, which I would not recommend you to do you are doing it this way `style="background-color:#000000;"`. You really should use an external css file. Because in my opinion HTML is for the markup and css is for the styling, and if you have to change the layout in the future you don't know if you have set the styling in the css or in the html. So try to stick one method. Also never ever use body 2 times.
2. Give your input fields an ID so you could easily access them via `javascript`, or as you tagged your question `jQuery` but reading through your HTML Markup, I can see that you have not included jQuery yet.
3. Examples of using jQuery to get the values you want. As you have seen I have edited your html markup a bit, so its cleaner and has more structure:
   http://jsfiddle.net/pmjVP/